# What are my options for parent when using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, awt, jfilechooser

I'm trying to show a window for file choosing as it follows:

```
public class XMLElementCounter() {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        elementCounter();
    }
    
    static void elementCounter() {

        try {

            final FileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(defaultDirectory);
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(parent);
            
            ...

        }

}
```

First i declared the elementCounter directly in the main function and i called as parent fc, which showed the window as expected, but as i modularized it, it stopped showing anything. When i use null, it shows the screen behind every other window, which is annoying.

How can i know which is the parent i'm looking for, and where can i learn about it?

Comment: Does your application have any other windows/frames?

Comment: @VGR just that one

Comment: @VGR i'm using a case where i declare a JFileChooser on 2 different cases, does it count as different windows? It isn't working on it's first iteration anyway

Comment: Create a new JFrame.  It only needs a title and a single JLabel in its content pane.  I recommend the JLabel have a large border, like `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(200, 200, 200, 200)`.  Show the JFrame when your program starts up, before showing any file choosers.  You can then use that JFrame as the parent.

Comment: @VGR i have options on my console, will it show up over that? I wan't it to open after i enter the switch

Comment: If you are using the console for user input, you should be using the console to request a file name.  Mixing console input and windowed GUI input is confusing.

Comment: @VGR man, i'm using it, i know how i want it